# R is not resolved

Tags: android

Hey ive had the R not resolved problem for a while, so i started a new project and realized the the R not resolved problem is becouse i added a android:background="#09900" to a button in the XML :

```
 <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnMap"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#09900"
       android:text="map"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent" />
```

When i remove the background, its all fine. So i still have another project which is quite a bit larger that has the R not resolved problem. but i cant find what is causing it because even here the background="#09900" is not registered as an error or warning. Any idea what i should look for or how i can find the problem more easily ?

EDIT: I realize the error in this code, i was hoping for ways or tips to avoid errors similar to this, since the editor does not warn you about them. I still have a large project with an error like this and i have no idea where to look for it. Im not asking about the error in the code provided here.

Comment: try using #099000  6 letter hexcode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set **color** code in color file. It should be  **6 or 8 digit code** and not 5.

`'android:background="#09900"'`

Comment: Yeah i figured that out, i was hoping on some tips to avoid error similar to this, that the editor does not warn you about. I still have to figure out what i did wrong in the other project, and if its something like 5 digits instead of 4, its going to be hard to figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

> R not resolved Android Studio

Because **`android:background="#09900"`** Is Not a valid color code

The color code must be **6 or 8 digit**